# ionic ion-nav-view with 3 level not working

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I have the following states:

```
 $stateProvider

    .state('app', {
    url: '/app',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
    controller: 'AppCtrl'
  })
.state('app.myClients', {
  url: '/myClients',
  //templateUrl: 'templates/myClients/myClients.html',
  views: {
    'menuContent': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/myClients/myClients.html',
      controller: 'clientController'
    }
  }
})
.state('app.myClients.rapida', {
  url: '/rapida',
  //templateUrl: 'templates/myClients/myClients.html',
  views: {
    'content_rapida@menuContent@app': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/myClients/partials/rapida.html',
  //    controller: 'qSearchController'
    }
  }
})
```

menu.html

```
<ion-side-menus hide-back-button="true" enable-menu-with-back-views="true" ng-controller="menuCtrl">
    <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-side-menu-content>
```

myClients.html

```
<div class="div_clients" ng-controller="clientController">

  <ion-nav-view name="content_rapida"></ion-nav-view>
  <ion-nav-view name="content_lenta"></ion-nav-view>

  <div class="clientFilter">
    <h1 class="searchTitle">
      FILTROS
    </h1>

    <div class="filtereRow">
      Filtros (0)
      <div class="executeBt">
        <button class="execute" ng-click="">Ejecutar<i class="ion-ios-loop execute-icon"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

rapida.html

```
<h1>HI guys!</h1>
```

This works

```
/app/myClients
```

This doesn't works

```
/app/myClients/rapida
```

Comment: Do you get any kind of error?

Comment: @adeel_s There are not errors in console :(

Comment: I have updated the question, to make it cleaner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did it!

I changed this

```
.state('app.myClients.rapida', {
  url: '/rapida',
  //templateUrl: 'templates/myClients/myClients.html',
  views: {
    'content_rapida@menuContent@app': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/myClients/partials/rapida.html',
      controller: 'qSearchController'
    }
  }
})
```

To this

```
.state('app.myClients.rapida', {
  url: '/rapida',
  templateUrl: 'templates/myClients/myClients.html',
  views: {
    'content_rapida': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/myClients/partials/rapida.html',
      controller: 'qSearchController'
    }
  }
})
```

Note that I have to use templateUrl twice.

Answer (score 0):

Hace you tried with 
     **'content_rapida'**
instead of 
     **'content_rapida@menuContent@app'**
at state definition?

Your view should already identify 'content_rapida' inside the parent view...